# How to make column heading letters bold in rhandsontable in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

How to make column heading bold text in rhandsontable in shiny package of r?

I have a rhandsontable in shiny that I want to make bold the text in the header. How can I do it? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add some `style` to your table as so:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("table1"),
  tags$style(type="text/css", "#table1 th {font-weight:bold;}")
)

server=function(input, output, session) {

  output$table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(mtcars,rowHeaders=F)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image]

Comment: great!! Thank you

Comment: How to add style to selected column headers only and not to all the columns?

Answer (score 1):

rhandsontable is an interface to the Handsontable.js library, so it's possible to customize it using CSS. Take the following data frame:

```
DF = data.frame(column.one = 1:10,
                column.two = TRUE)

rhandsontable(DF)
```

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPrhF.png) without any customization.

But if you specify using CSS, you can reference it:

```
DF = data.frame(column.one = 1:10,
                column.two = TRUE)

func = "function (col) {  # custom CSS
  switch (col) {
    case 0:
      return '<b>Bold</b> and <em>Italics</em>';

    case 1:
      return '<em>Bold</em> and <b>Italics</b>';
   }
 }"

 rhandsontable(DF, colHeaders = htmlwidgets::JS(func))
```

And you end up with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz2wX.png).

Make sure to specify the colHeaders argument when you call the rhandsontable function.

Comment: library(shiny)
     library(datasets)
     library(rhandsontable)

     ui=fluidPage(

br(), br(), actionButton("update", "go", class="success"), br(), br(),  
rHandsontableOutput("table1")
)


server=function(input, output, session) {

mt=reactive({

datacopy= data.table(mtcars)
datacopy[16, "wt"] <- NA
datacopy

})

output$table1=renderRHandsontable({
rhandsontable(mt())
})

}

shinyApp(ui,server)

Comment: How should I bold the column heading and also Once I click "go" button I want 468 to be bold.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple handsontable in your app then you can do it all together for all the tables at once.

```
if(interactive()){
    library(shiny)
    library(rhandsontable)
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
        rHandsontableOutput("table1"),
        br(),
        rHandsontableOutput("table2"),
        br(),
        tags$style(type="text/css", ".ht_master:not(.innerBorderTop) thead tr.lastChild th, .ht_master:not(.innerBorderTop) thead tr:last-child th, .ht_master:not(.innerBorderTop)~.handsontable thead tr.lastChild th, .ht_master:not(.innerBorderTop)~.handsontable thead tr:last-child th {
  font-weight: bold;
} .wtHolder {
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}")
    )
    
    server=function(input, output, session) {
        
        output$table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
            rhandsontable(mtcars,rowHeaders=F)
        })
        
        output$table2 <- renderRHandsontable({
            rhandsontable(iris,rowHeaders=F)
        })
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui,server)
}
```

Keep Coding!