# How to display specific column header in Rhandsontable in a particular color using css?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, rhandsontable

I would like change the header color of specific columns to a specific color using css. For example can someone suggest on how to change the color of the header 'mpg', 'hp' and 'gear' to red color, and  change the color of 'disp', 'wt' and 'carb' to blue color in the following example table?

My question is almost similar to the question posted in this forum [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874347/how-to-make-column-heading-letters-bold-in-rhandsontable-in-shiny).

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("table1"),
  tags$style(type="text/css", "#table1 th {font-weight:bold;}")
)

server=function(input, output, session) {

  output$table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(head(mtcars),rowHeaders=F)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lastly I had similar issue to make custom HTML header for rhandsontable and found this thread. The solution is really nice. But I also ran into a problem with using `hot_col()` after setting `colHeaders = table_headers_html` within `rhandsontable()`.

I was able to make following workaround; it just modifies the column headers directly in the object created with `rhandsontable()` - after setting desired options with `hot_col()`.

```
server=function(input, output, session) {

    output$table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable_object <- rhandsontable(
            head(mtcars),
            rowHeaders=F
        ) %>%
          hot_col(col = mpg, allowInvalid = TRUE)

        rhandsontable_object$x$colHeaders <- table_headers_html

        rhandsontable_object
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It needs some knowledge of HTML. One way to do it is to convert column names from plain text to HTML:

```r
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(purrr)
library(glue)
table_headers <- colnames(mtcars)
table_headers_html <- purrr::map_chr(table_headers, function(column){
    if(column %in% c('mpg', 'hp', 'gear')){
        color = "red"
    } else if (column %in% c('disp', 'wt', 'carb')) {
        color = "blue"
    } else {
        color = "black"
    }
    glue::glue("<span style='color:{color}'>{column}</span>")
})
```

```r
> table_headers_html
 [1] "<span style='color:red'>mpg</span>"    "<span style='color:black'>cyl</span>"  "<span style='color:blue'>disp</span>" 
 [4] "<span style='color:red'>hp</span>"     "<span style='color:black'>drat</span>" "<span style='color:blue'>wt</span>"   
 [7] "<span style='color:black'>qsec</span>" "<span style='color:black'>vs</span>"   "<span style='color:black'>am</span>"  
[10] "<span style='color:red'>gear</span>"   "<span style='color:blue'>carb</span>"
```

Once you have the column headers in HTML, you can do the following in server codes:

```r
server=function(input, output, session) {

    output$table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(
            head(mtcars),
            rowHeaders=F,
            colHeaders = table_headers_html
        )
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: It was a great learning experience and sure would be very useful to many others like me.

Comment: The only challenge need to overcome now is that when I use 'colHeaders' in rhandsontable() I am not able to use 'renderer' in hot_col(). Any suggestion?